# Use of Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml files in a themed Maui app

Tags: xaml, maui

When converting a .net maui app to use themes, is it best practice to keep Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml files in the project and reference them in the themes? Or should what was in those files be moved to the individual .xaml files?

- If the colors/styles files are retained then I can avoid some duplication of common definitions in the theme files. But clearing the current theme and loading a new one (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming?view=net-maui-7.0#load-a-theme-at-runtime)) becomes more complex because I would need to selectively remove only the theme entry from the merged dictionaries.
- Conversely, if everything goes into the .xaml files then I have potential for duplication of values that are the same across themes.

Thoughts on best practice?

Answer (score 1):

> is it best practice to keep Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml files in the
> project and reference them in the themes? Or should what was in those
> files be moved to the individual .xaml files?

This depends on the actual needs of the application to decide which one to use. It is not appropriate to say which one is good and which one is not. It can only be said that in different scenarios, which one is more suitable to use.
There are even times when we need to use a combination of both.

You can tell us your specific needs and we will advise you.

For more information about style in maui,you can check document: [Theme an app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/theming?view=net-maui-7.0#load-a-theme-at-runtime).

Comment: Thanks for responding. The app in question is fairly simple and I just wanted to have a background colour be conditional on the system theme. I explored using themes but in the end I just used `AppThemeBinding` to conditionally switch the colour and kept the Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml files.

Comment: What prompted my question was actually the documentation that you linked to. The example code shows how to clear the `MergedDictionaries` collection and add the new theme in response to a system theme change. If using themes *and* Colors/Styles files then the collection will actually contain three entries - one for the theme and one each for the Colors and Styles. But clearing it removes the non-theme resources too, and there doesn't appear to be a way to add them back as they don't generate classes that are visible to me - their xaml doesn't have an `x:Class` attribute. ...

Comment: ... This blows away any definitions from the Colors/Styles files after a theme change. It's relatively simple to selectively remove just the theme resources though, once you understand the problem. I'll log an issue with the docs.